# Basic Authentication for API Call not working on VPN

Tags: spring-boot, rest, vpn, cisco

I am trying to make an API call to a server using Basic Authentication which works fine on a local network, but when using a VPN the Requests with a Basic Authentication are getting timed out in Spring Boot Application.

Is there any way to bypass this?
Or any Issue which might be causing the same?

Comment: VPNs are not that smart to block you auth. There is no reason to think that VPN could affect OSI level 5. First of all you need to ensure that VPN connection works as intended, i.e. check networking at Level 3 ( ping, telnet, routing etc).

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny i am trying to make an API call which works fine in the browser but when using any other application http service, in this case Spring Rest Operation methods it simply says connection timed out everytime when on VPN. But without any VPN the same works perfect.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue!

Answer (score 0):

Try Using CNTLM on proxy networks where in most cases authentication headers are blocked and need to be tunneled in a special way which can be handled by CNTLM

Comment: Could you elaborate on this one? What do you mean?